# Changing select list to dropdown ul list with links

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a mistake and created my website with select dropdown lists and now on mobile every single dropdown is opened like a popup that looks like this monstrosity:

[image: Text]

For example I have this dropdown list used to sort items with PHP function so I would like to convert it into regular dropdown list (ul li), but I I'm not sure how to push same PHP functions for sorting.

If I create UL with  links, do I put PHP function into href or I leave it as attribute?

Or alternatively can I somehow stop mobile devices from opening as those ugly popups?

This is my dropdown select list made for sorting:

```
<select name="sort-me" id="sort-me" >
  <option value="">Sort by</option>
  <option value="0" <?=$sort=='0' ? 'selected' : ''?> sort="sort-price-up">
    Sort by price (ascending)
  </option>
  <option value="1" <?=$sort=='1' ? 'selected' : ''?> sort="sort-price-down">
    Sort by price (descending)
  </option>
</select>
```

I have tried converting it like this, but this won't work:

```
<div class="dropdown-wrap">
  <button id="sort-me" name="sort-me" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Sort by
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="0" <?=$sort=='0' ? 'selected' : ''?> sort="sort-price-up">Sort by price (ascending)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" value="1" <?=$sort=='1' ? 'selected' : ''?> sort="sort-price-down">Sort by price (descending)</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just my opinion, but what you are calling a "monstrosity", I would call a nearly-100% accessible, browser-native interface that looks consistent across all other sites on that device. The style might not look like the site's main theme, but it is intended for me to interact with which should almost always take priority. Just my two cents.

Comment: "_regular dropdown list (ul li)_" `<ul>` is an unordered list, not a dropdown list.

Comment: That's true and it would work on some things, but as this is ecommerce website and there is simply way too many filters to leave it like that. Also clients aren't pleased with it as well.

Comment: To your question, I'm not really sure what it is? PHP makes HTML. The fact that it is a `select` vs `ul` shouldn't matter. The exception would be if you have a form that sends data to the server on change. In that case you could optionally have a hidden form and have your onchange work with the UL/LI stuff and send data to the hidden form

Comment: @brombeer yeah I know, I was just using as much tags I could think of so this might help someone in future searches.

Comment: As it relates specifically to the interface, I think you should determine what the expected interaction and result is, and that will yield the tool. Should there be something that is clickable, and the resulting URL can be shared or indexed by engines? Then you want a link. Should there be several options with a "submit" button once the user is ready to change things? Then a form. Should there be individual buttons that change the interface when the user clicks them? Them maybe HTML buttons with JS. Should items always be hidden until the user interacts with them somehow?

Comment: @Chris Haas, I just edited in what I tried. I'm trying to find a script where this function is called, but since I only have access over ftp, it takes some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you understand what you mean correctly:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbGjw.png)

```
 <div class="dropdown-wrap">
    <button id="sort-me" name="sort-me" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Sort by
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item <?= $sort == '0' ? 'bi-check-lg' : '' ?>" value="0" sort="sort-price-up">Sort by price (ascending)</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item <?= $sort == '0' ? 'bi-check-lg' : '' ?>" value="1" sort="sort-price-down">Sort by price (descending)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use bootstrap icon and the rest is up to you where and how to use it.